# writing to excel from arraylist using while loop (netbeans)

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

I'm writing a program to create a simple invoice from a database of products. the user has selected products and quantity which have been added to an array list, I am having problems closing the writable notebook as it doesn't seem to want to do this once the while loop has run. I have limited knowledge as to the functioning of the java.jxl methods so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void write() {
    try {
        WritableWorkbook myexel = Workbook.createWorkbook(new
                File("C:\\Users\\paulm\\Desktop\\Invoice.xls"));
        WritableSheet mysheet = myexel.createSheet("MYSHEET", 0);
        Label l = new Label(0, 0, "Products :");
        mysheet.addCell(l);
        int count = 0;
        while(SelectedArray.size() >=count ){
            int n = count + 1;
            String prodtoadd = SelectedArray.get(count).getSelected();
            Label ln = new Label(1, n, prodtoadd);
            mysheet.addCell(ln);
            myexel.write();
           count++;
        }
        myexel.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think you check your while loop and format code like this.
while(SelectedArray.size() >=count ){
                int n = count + 1;
                String prodtoadd = SelectedArray.get(count).getSelected();
                Label ln = new Label(1, n, prodtoadd);
                mysheet.addCell(ln);
                count++;
            }
    myexel.write();
    myexel.close();
```